# What does "Stream did not contain valid UTF-8" mean?

Tags: utf-8, stream, rust

I'm creating a simple HTTP server. I need to read the requested image and send it to browser. I'm using this code:

```
fn read_file(mut file_name: String) -> String {
    file_name = file_name.replace("/", "");
    if file_name.is_empty() {
        file_name = String::from("index.html");
    }

    let path = Path::new(&file_name);
    if !path.exists() {
        return String::from("Not Found!");
    }
    let mut file_content = String::new();
    let mut file = File::open(&file_name).expect("Unable to open file");
    let res = match file.read_to_string(&mut file_content) {
        Ok(content) => content,
        Err(why) => panic!("{}",why),
    };

    return file_content;
}
```

This works if the requested file is text based, but when I want to read an image I get the following message:

> stream did not contain valid UTF-8

What does it mean and how to fix it?

Comment: UTF-8 is a way of encoding strings using bytes. As with most encodings, not every sequence of bytes is going to correspond to something you can interpret as a UTF-8 string. Since your file is an image, you probably just want to read the raw bytes. `bytes` and `read_to_end` could help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [documentation for `String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html) describes it as:

> A UTF-8 encoded, growable string.

The [Wikipedia definition of UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) will give you a great deal of background on what that is. The short version is that computers use a unit called a [byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) to represent data. Unfortunately, these blobs of data represented with bytes have no intrinsic meaning; that has to be provided from outside. UTF-8 is one way of interpreting a sequence of bytes, as are file formats like [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG).

UTF-8, like most text encodings, has specific requirements and sequences of bytes that are *valid* and *invalid*. Whatever image you have tried to load contains a sequence of bytes that cannot be interpreted as a UTF-8 string; this is what the error message is telling you.

---

To fix it, you should not use a `String` to hold arbitrary collections of bytes. In Rust, that's better represented by a [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html):

```
fn read_file(mut file_name: String) -> Vec<u8> {
    file_name = file_name.replace("/", "");
    if file_name.is_empty() {
        file_name = String::from("index.html");
    }

    let path = Path::new(&file_name);
    if !path.exists() {
        return String::from("Not Found!").into();
    }
    let mut file_content = Vec::new();
    let mut file = File::open(&file_name).expect("Unable to open file");
    file.read_to_end(&mut file_content).expect("Unable to read");
    file_content
}
```

---

To evangelize a bit, this is a great aspect of why Rust is a nice language. Because there is a type that represents "a set of bytes that is guaranteed to be a valid UTF-8 string", we can write safer programs since we know that this invariant will always be true. We don't have to keep checking throughout our program to "make sure" it's still a string.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I used your example but now I get this error : `invalid utf-8: invalid byte near index 0`

Comment: @smoqadam that's very difficult to believe. There is no longer any code shown that tries to make arbitrary bytes into UTF-8. Perhaps you have code that takes the `Vec` returned and tries to make it into a `String` again? It's still the same set of bytes; they can **never** be transformed to UTF-8 in their present state.

Comment: Yes, I need to convert it to string and send to browser. how can do that?

Comment: @smoqadam you *cannot* treat the raw data of an image as a UTF-8 string. The good news is that [the HTTP 1.0 protocol](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html) (as well as 1.1, likely 2.0) does not require that the data sent in the body of the request / response be a UTF-8 string. It's perfectly valid to send back raw bytes, so long as the appropriate headers are specified.

Comment: thanks again. I'm new to rust and confused. would you give me an example how can I read an image and return it to the browser?

Comment: @smoqadam it depends a lot on the libraries you are using. The last comment from Shepmaster is pretty clear, but it requires a bit of background knowledge about the way HTTP works. Maybe you should consider reading about the HTTP protocol?